# Where to find "dynamic web project" version of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I usually install the Java EE version of eclipse, but this has a lot of confusing stuff we don't need, and is missing key elements like git we do need.

There used to be a version of eclipse called WTP or WPT or similar for web site development using java/tomcat etc.  This seems to not exist as an eclipse version now.

I installed the "java" edition of eclipse, and expected to find some kind of plugin to give dynamic web projects under "software update", but there is none.  Why doesnt elcipse have an out of the box way of installing the standard essential eclipse plugins?

I found a post which says WTP is under the software update repo: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno but its not there.

I found some links an eclipse webtools project: http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=webtools#  The getting started link is broken, and I can't find any information on how to get WPT into eclipse - I see I can download the WTP project source code, but no install instructions.

If I cant get WTP into eclipse, the other option is to install the Java EE version, and then look for the git plugin, which might be easier as it exists on the marketplace (but WTP doesnt).

Having done some more research, the WTP project site doesnt mention any version compatible with Juno release, only Galileo, Helios and Indigo.

In the meantime I thought I would setup tomcat.  Great, thats not available either.  Under the logical "Window->preferences->Server->Runtime Environemnts->add" are no servers.  under "Download Additional server adapters" are lots of servers, but no tomcat.  Anyone know how to get tomcat into eclipse?  This never used to be this hard...

Answer (score 2):

Gave up, installed Java EE version of eclipse, WTP and Tomcat work in that version.